# Switch case syntax with textview and imageview

Tags: android, textview, imageview, switch-statement, case

I am a beginner in `Android` platform and need some help.

I'm making an app that needs to grab a random value of a `TextView` and in accordance with the value, the app will change a picture in `ImageView`.

I made the following syntax:

```
        x = (int) (Math.random()*4);
        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(x));


        switch(){
            case 0: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1); break;
            case 1: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2); break;
            case 2: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3); break;
            case 3: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img4); break;
        }
```

What should I put in the line: `switch()` and `case 0,1,2 etc.` to make it function properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put x

```
   switch(x) {
    ....
}
```